# Why am I getting "Unable to locate the server named localhost" error in Postman?

Tags: localhost, postman

I get the following error:

```
    <B>
Description: Unable to locate the server named "
        <em>localhost</em>" --- the server does not have a DNS entry.  Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists.  Double-check the name and try again.
    </B>
```

When I try to access the following url:

```
http://localhost:8812/
```

I think it might have something to do with my proxy settings, but I am very new to these kind of things, so I am unsure

Comment: Run `ping localhost` in your command line and check whether there is any DNS error. If yes, then it is a DNS problem and has nothing to do with Postman

Answer (score 1):

You could try accessing it via http://127.0.0.1:8812/ instead, seems like your local DNS resolver doesn't work properly.